# Contiki Rime stack how to get the broadcasting ID in Example_Broadcast

Tags: microcontroller, contiki, texas-instruments

I am working on the broadcasting example of contiki's Rime stack :

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/rime/example-broadcast.c

When receiving a broadcast I can easily read out the senders id:

```
broadcast_recv(struct broadcast_conn *c, const linkaddr_t *from)
{
  printf("Sender: %d.%d\n", from->u8[0], from->u8[1]);
}
```

But how can I get "my"/current node's ID?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local address in Contiki is stored in `linkaddr_node_addr`:

```
#include "net/linkaddr.h"
...
printf("Local: %d.%d\n", linkaddr_node_addr.u8[0], linkaddr_node_addr.u8[1]);
```

There is also another variable: `uint16_t node_id`, at least on most platforms. It is by default equal to `linkaddr_node_addr.u8[0] + (linkaddr_node_addr.u8[1] << 8)`. Add `#include "sys/node-id.h"` for that.

Comment: Im gonna check it later, awesome. May I know how you know that? Im really struggling with their documentations.

Comment: The way I learned was mostly by looking at the sources. Check out [Contiki-NG](http://contiki-ng.org/), it has improved documentation.

Answer (score 0):

add this header:`#include "sys/node-id.h"`
And then using`"node_id"` you can obtain the self id of the node!